# DataTable funciona com Pesquisa em banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Sou iniciante em algumas áreas da programação.

Recentemente me indicaram usar [DataTable](https://datatables.net), fiz alguns teste usando `Html` puro e li algumas coisas sobre. Os testes feitos com `HTML` foram bem legais eu vi as funcionalidades, gostei bastante de como funciona. Porem, quando tentei usar junto com o `PHP`, mais especificamente em uma pesquisa com banco de dados MYSQL, o resultado acabou sendo bem diferente do esperado e as funcionalidades principais acabaram não funcionando da mesma forma que no Html.

Isso ocorre pq a DataTable não funciona junto com Php, banco de dados MYSQL, ou pq tenho que fazer de uma forma diferente?

Algumas das funcionalidades que citei são:

1. Quebrar pagina na tela e poder passar a mesma ( a principal no caso )
2. Ao apertar na coluna fazer o filtro em ordem alfabética
3. campo pesquisar... e etc.

segue o código que estou usando.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table, {
        alwaysCloneTop: true
    });
} );
</script>
```

```css
  body { font-size: 140%; padding: 1em; }
div.FixedHeader_Cloned table { margin: 0 !important }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Prologue by HTML5 UP</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main3.css" />
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>CPF</th>
  <th>Data de Nascimento</th>
  <th colspan="3">Ações</th>

</tr>
</thead>


<?php   
      include_once "conexao.php";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE tipo_perfil LIKE '%CLIENTE%'";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            if($result){
            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>

<tbody>
       <tr>
           <td> <?php  echo $linha['nome_usuario'];?></td>
           <td> <?php  echo $linha['cpf_usuario'];?></td>
           <td> <?php  echo $linha['data_nascimento'];?></td>       
           <td><div class="botaodiv"> <?php echo "<a  href = ?editar=".$linha['id_usuario']." >+ Informações</a>";?></div></td>
           <td><div class="botaodiv"> <?php echo "<a  href = ?deletar=".$linha['id_usuario'].">Editar</a>";?></div></td>
           <td><div class="botaodiv"> <?php echo "<a  href = ?deletar=".$linha['id_usuario'].">Excluir</a>";?></div></td>
       </tr>
</tbody>

        <?php
      }
      }
        ?>

</table>
```

Comment: No caso informado, EU prefiro usar o DataTable nessas circunstâncias com uma função ajax e puxar todo o conteúdo que deverá ser mostrado através de json e fazendo o "build" da tabela sem intermédio DIRETO do php na página... É uma forma mais eficaz, rápida e simples de se fazer... Você poderia acabar dando uma lida e vendo alguns exemplos sobre a minha dica no site deles: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas teria como fazer sem usar uma função ajax ?. Ainda não usei ajax em nenhum de meus códigos e por isso se torne bem difícil eu adaptar para meu código no momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja este exemplo:

O biblioteca `datatable` funciona com PHP, seja puro ou utilizando `framework`.

Seria um pouco extenso escrever um código aqui para representar o funcionamento.

Mas com poucas pesquisas, é possível obter exemplos.

[demo](https://coderexample.com/demo/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/)

Aqui é possivel detalhar melhor a demostração acima
[acessar](https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/)

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que seja possível sim, utilizando [ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax).